# Plotting doesn't work in Jupyter-notebook (octave language) in Arch Linux System, I have Installed gnuplot

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, gnuplot, octave, fltk

I am trying to plot a graph in jupyter notebook and my language is Octave. I searched through various forums, where many of them suggested installing gnuplot, include graphics_toolkit("gnuplot").

I tried those, but none of the techniques worked. I guess, from the error, it is searching for the files related to fltk. Although, the graphics toolkit has been changed to gnuplot.
Thank you in advance.
When I write in this code in Jupyter

```
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
plot(x, sin(x))
```

```
failed to load: libfltk_gl.so.1.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: what operating system are you on?

Comment: I am on Arch Linux.

Comment: libfltk_gl.so.1.3 has to be somewhere on your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  See if you can find libfltk... in /usr/lib or somewhere on your machine.  Then add the path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: You can also set the gnuplot's default terminal in the file `~/.gnuplot`:  add there a line `set term qt` or `set term x11` or whatever.